# Missing one byte when transferring an image over Socket Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem transferring a file over socket.
I Wrote a simple client / server app and the client takes a screenshot and send it to server.
The problem is the file is not completed whatever i do, It's always missing the first byte from the array which makes the photo damaged.
When I open the photo in any hex editor and compare the original photo with the one that the client sent, I can see the missing byte, as if I add it, the photo opens without the problem. The size of the sent file missing just one byte !
Here is a photo for the problem :

Original photo

[image: Original photo]

sent photo
[image: sent photo]

Here is the code :

Server ( Receiver ) :

```
byte[] buf;
InputStream inp;
try (BufferedOutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("final.jpeg")))) {
    buf = new byte[s.getReceiveBufferSize()];
    inp = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    Thread.sleep(200);
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inp.read(buf)) >0){
    out1.write(buf,0,len);
    }
    out1.flush();
     inp.close();
     out1.close();
}
```

Client ( Sender ):

```
BufferedImage screenshot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "jpeg", os);
ImageIO.write(screenshot, "jpeg", new File("test.jpeg"));
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(os.toByteArray());
out.close();
```

I have tried to send the array with the same way I receive it but no lock. I have tried with, and without buffered, I have tried flush in both sides, I tried to turn off Nod antivirus, Tried a sleep when sending length, 
I almost tried everything without success . 
I have tried on both, My pc and a virtual machine windows 7 !
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit :
First 10 bytes from the original file :
[image: Original]

first 10 bytes from the sent file :
[image]

Comment: Sending the data first to a ByteArrayOutputStream is a waste of time and resources, but shouldn't be part of the problem.  Can you show us the first 10 bytes in that ByteArrayOutputStream, and explain what data you expect to see instead?

Comment: Here is the original file first 10 bytes : -1,40,-1,32,0,16,74,70,73,70
and the sent file is missing the first -1 but rest are the same !!
Edit : if you have another way to send the photo without closing the socket, It'll be helpful .

Comment: could you do without `DataInputStream` in server and read directly from socket's input stream? Also why do you call `Thread.sleep(200)` in the server?

Comment: I'm agreeing with diginoise: we know now that ImageIO is writing the image correctly (you just said the ByteArrayOutputStream has the correct data), and the output streams are too well tested to be the culprit.  That leaves something funny with DataInputStream.  Try just reading from the raw stream on the server.

Comment: the 200 ms tried to read the size before start receiving data, I'll try with input stream .

Comment: Tried that now with no luck ! I did read directly from input stream and the first byte still missing !
Here what I did :
byte[] tt = new byte[s.getReceiveBufferSize()];
                inp.read(tt);

when reading the first 10 bytes, still the first one missing !

Comment: I think Mick's answer below might be correct.  You've only shown us part of the code.  Any place before the code you've shown us might be doing a "read" and eating that first byte.

Comment: To make helping you easier (or even maybe possible) create proper [mcve]. You don't need to include any file, just use some short byte array containing start of that image. You also don't need to include code responsible for writing anything to file, just print received array to console.

Comment: Nothing there ! It's just the start of method ! calling it after the client exactly connected

Comment: I have edited the post and added the first 10 bytes from every file , original and sent one ! Take a look please

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Take your time and provide proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)). There is an high chance you will even find source of your problem while creating it.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, but I already have just this method with connection method, nothing more, so I know the problem not in the connection itself because I can receive a connection from client, and the second method is to capture the screenshot and send it to server. That's all my code so I'm really stuck in the middle of no where !!

Comment: @Pshemo You remember incorrectly. `DataOutputStream` does not use headers or any superimposed protocol

Comment: Are you sure you are not consuming any other bytes before starting read a image?

Comment: It was my fault , It was in client side when I opened DataInputStream and DataOutputStream and forgot to close it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does not lose data. Somewhere prior to executing the server code you posted, you have executed a single `InputStream.read()` of one byte, possibly in a misguided attempt to test for end of stream.

The sleep is just literally a waste of time. Remove it. You don't need the `DataInput/OutputStreams` either.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that `DataInputStream` signals end of stream by returning value `-1` from `read()` therefore your server reading loop should look like this:

```
while ((len = inp.read(buf)) != -1){
    out1.write(buf,0,len);
}
```

Perhaps this helps.

Comment: I tried that before with the same results unfortunately.

Comment: fair enough - please keep the condition as `len != -1` anyway as some streams can wait for data arrival and might choose to return 0 rather than block.

Comment: I'll keep it in mind thank you.. But the problem is not solved yet, so any other ideas ? Thanks

Comment: "some streams can wait for data arrival and might choose to return 0" Actually, it's the other way around. According to its contract, `InputStream.read(byte[])` may only return 0 if you pass it zero-length buffer. There are implementations of `InputStream` that return -1 when the *current* end of input is reached, rather than blocking for more input that may never come (some serial I/O libraries, specifically). But an `InputStream` must block, rather than returning 0, or it is broken.

Comment: I tried with DataInputStream for an example, but the same result it here, Changed the sender code to match the receiver but no luck ! Changed >o to != -1 and nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The client code looks fine. Must be the server. You only posted the part when "some" input stream is written to a file. What happens before? Anyone doing a read() on the input stream?

Sorry for writing this in the "answer" section. Apparently, I cannot comment yet.

Comment: I think it's in server yes, but I tried to read the whole array with input stream with the same result !! Noting changed.

Comment: This is the whole code for receiving, Noting more or less, just the finish message at the end !

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was my fault ! I was looking for something wrong in server side but the fault was in client side ! I opened a DataInputStream to read the order coming from server without closing it and that was the problem.

Comment: The re is no such thing as a `DataInputReader`.

Comment: When the client connect, It receives some data from server and send some without closing it ( in and out ) ! I thought the issue in the server itself ( As people said ) without looking at the client.

Comment: I meant DataInputStream , Sorry for that

Comment: A `DataInputStream` alone cannot cause this problem, let alone an unclosed one. Somewhere you actively consumed one byte of data.

Comment: Yes it's since it's trying to read something and forward it to another stream to read the order coming from the client ! Like : listen to client, define what kind of order he sent, then forward the order to the right method. since the other method is trying to read, so the main DataInputStream already took one byte. So what I did is to send the packet with a header and EOP to get the whole packet without loosing a byte. Or simply: close the main InputStream and read the incoming whole packet from the secondary method which has DataInputStream.